# Unable to use intent extra from onStartCommand

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am trying to make a Android app with a service (Floating widget). Since I am not a pro-programmer, I did not use touch listener to change position of that widget for lot of reasons. But I want user to have options to change position (some preferred locations only)  of that widget, and that options will be available in an activity which invoked the service. I am passing data as intent extra from my activity to service, which is to be obtained from service `onStartCommand()`. The problem I am facing now- I am unable to use data obtained from `onStartCommand()` in `onCreate()`. Seems the service is created before `onStartCommand()` is called and I am getting null pointer exception as some of my variables are not obtaining values from `onStartCommand()`. I have checked, that these variables are getting values when I use any clickable objects (e.g: press any button view in service), I used a dummy toast for this.

Please share your valuable opinion on how to overcome this problem.

```
public class MainFloatingWidget extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private View myFloatingView, myCollapsedView, myExpandedView;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    private String position;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        myFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_main_floating_widget, null);

        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.addView(myFloatingView, params);

        myCollapsedView = myFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.collapsedViewMainService);

        myExpandedView = myFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.expandedViewMainService);

        myCollapsedView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                myCollapsedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myExpandedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
        });

        myExpandedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonBack).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myCollapsedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myExpandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        myExpandedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonClose).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                windowManager.removeView(myFloatingView);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        if(position.equals("Right-Middle")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER;
            }else if(position.equals("Right-Top")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.END | Gravity.TOP;
            }else if(position.equals("Right-Bottom")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.END | Gravity.BOTTOM;
            }else if(position.equals("Left-Middle")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER;
            }else if(position.equals("Left-Top")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
            }else if(position.equals("Left-Bottom")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.BOTTOM;
            }else{
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            }

            windowManager.updateViewLayout(myFloatingView, params);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       
        position = (String) intent.getExtras().get("POSITION");
        

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure onCreate call before onStartCommand and onCreate only call one time but onStartCommand can call many times

Comment: That's right, but is there any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreate` will call before `onStartCommand` and only call one time when `Service` init so you should move your code handle `position` to inside `onStartCommand`

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        position = (String) intent.getExtras().get("POSITION");
        if(position.equals("Right-Middle")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER;
            }else if(position.equals("Right-Top")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.END | Gravity.TOP;
            }else if(position.equals("Right-Bottom")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.END | Gravity.BOTTOM;
            }else if(position.equals("Left-Middle")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER;
            }else if(position.equals("Left-Top")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
            }else if(position.equals("Left-Bottom")){
                params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.BOTTOM;
            }else{
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            }

        windowManager.updateViewLayout(myFloatingView, params);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```